# Google Play Warning: SSL Error Handler Vulnerability

Tags: android, ssl, deezer

In my Android application, I use the Deezer SDK to play tracks. I recently received an email from Google with the following subject : "Google Play Warning: SSL Error Handler Vulnerability".
In this email, Google explains that my app has an ["unsafe implementation of the WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError handler. Specifically, the implementation ignores all SSL certificate validation errors, making your app vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. An attacker could change the affected WebView's content, read transmitted data (such as login credentials), and execute code inside the app using JavaScript."]

At the end of the email, the affected class is mentioned :
com.deezer.sdk.network.connect.Blues$Blues;

The Deezer SDK version I use is 0.10.17.

Does the 0.10.19 version solve this vulnerability issue ? There is nothing about that in the assiocated Release Notes.

Answer (score 2):

We are aware of this problem and It's fixed in the 0.10.20 version.

Comment: Thank you Tom for your answer. Do you have an idea of when the next release will be available ?

Comment: The 0.10.20 version is now available

Comment: @Tom can you please explain the solution in general terms for Google Play Warning: SSL Error Handler Vulnerability

Comment: You need to handle properly onReceivedSslError of your WebViewClient